# Setting environment variable in Heroku (via powershell) with special characters

Tags: django, powershell, heroku, environment-variables

Django 1.8, Heroku, Powershell.

I'm trying to set an Environment Variable for my django secret key in Heroku:

```
(venv) PS WORKFOLDER> heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=eoik6-&dnr9elgmrt7-%3hu_&37$3hg!9c6x!^khjr3!z*z&b4
```

I'm getting this error msg (3 times - since I have 3 ampersands in the string):

```
At line:1 char:77
+ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=eoik6-&dnr9elgmrt7-%3hu_&37$3hg!9c6x!^khjr3!z*z&b4
+                                                                             ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

When I tried the suggested solution (to put double quotes around the ampersands):

```
(venv) PS WORKFOLDER> heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=eoik6-"&"dnr9elgmrt7-%3hu_"&"37$3hg!9c6x!^khjr3!z*z"&"b4
```

I got this error:

```
SECRET_KEY: eoik6-
'dnr9elgmrt7-%3hu_' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'37$3hg!9c6x!^khjr3!z*z' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'b4' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I also tried escaping with slash, putting quotes around the whole string, etc. Same result.  So how can I set my environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Heroku, but assuming that `heroku` is executable and `config:set SECRET_KEY=eo...` is a commandline argument, you could  try this:

```powershell
& 'heroku' @('config:set', 'SECRET_KEY=eoik6-"&"dnr9elgmrt7-%3hu_"&"37$3hg!9c6x!^khjr3!z*z"&"b4')
```

Comment: I just tried it.  That works too!  Thanks! Seems our answers overlapped.

Comment: @woodduck Thanks, PS is somewhat tricky with external executables and commandline parameters, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29565317/4424236) to understand why this code works.

Answer (score 6):

I just tried a few things and it works when you put single quotes around the whole VALUE (and double quotes around the ampersands):

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY='eoik6-"&"dnr9elgmrt7-%3hu_"&"37$3hg!9c6x!^khjr3!z*z"&"b4'
```

verifiable by the command `heroku config`

Comment: you're a hero! G

Answer (score 0):

There is one more character that can cause issues, ')'. It produces a similar error: `x was unexpected at this time.`
Fortunately, the fix is exactly the same as with the ampersand - simply putting double quotes around it solves the issue.
Sample working solution:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY='7d"("5r9"^"dfghfd=fsdghw%9$")"zz")"yer68"^"346k-4_qndr%!c4h=r'
```

Edit: another problematic character, '^'. It's harder to spot since powershell simply omits it from the SECRET_KEY. It needs to be surrounded by double quotes too.