# Add SECRET_KEY to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I type

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY='x%_jcw%#a$qsv8)eyh+f_^#!xzx($wm0xrlk9!^(h=pjz*q3g='
```

on my Powershell I got this error:

`eyh+f_#!xzx($wm0xrlk9!(h was unexpected at this time.`

Please tell me if you know how to solve this. Thank you

Comment: Cant you simply just add the secret key to an .env file ? And then use its value using decouple ?

Comment: at Heroku there is Config Vars and with os.environ("key name") you can access it

Comment: Moreover if you are having problems with the powershell why not use the heroku dashboard.

Comment: [It looks like single-quoting the value should do the trick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules), as you've tried. Can you share the specific character(s) that are appearing in the error message? Or even the complete secret key and error message (of course you'd want to [generate a new one after doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41298963/354577) since `SECRET_KEY`s should never be shared.)

Comment: That's my complete secret key

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you switch to cmd, so you can run this command as it is, or you may modify it by escaping special characters [as described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130105/setting-environment-variable-in-heroku-via-powershell-with-special-characters) for example like ")" character, but it probably might not works with a too complex strings.