# Copying files with Copy-Item or robocopy

Tags: powershell, scripting, command-line-interface

I got the following problem. I have a folder C:\Users\Username. In that folder you can find folders like "Documents", "Favorites" etc.

What im trying to do is including only some of the folder to copy.

I was playing arround with `Robocopy XD` to exclude some folder but that is not acceptable cuz i cant know all the folder that may be there.

Then i tried `Get-ChildItem -include <some dir>`. Now i want to copy only the listed folders. But robocopy copies only the content of the folder and not the folder itself. Are there any other solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

First : don't forget to use `-recurse` on `Get-ChildItem` to grab all the structure in the object.
Then on `robocopy`:

- You need `/s` to include non-empty subdirectories and `/e` to include the all the subdirs
- `/b` and `/purge` is nice when you are doing backups - greatly increased speed . be careful with purge though
- `/xd <Directory>[ ...]` Excludes directories that match the specified names and paths. (or you can include just a list of the desired subdirs)

I use something like this:

```
$source = 'C:\hold\first test'
$destination = 'C:\hold\second test'
$robocopyOptions = @('/NJH', '/NJS')
$fileList = 'test.txt'
Start robocopy -args "$source $destination $fileList $robocopyOptions"
```

- see this question: [Powershell with Robocopy (or how the #$(*& do I pass arguments right?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562598/powershell-with-robocopy-or-how-the-do-i-pass-arguments-right)

Also the `log` option saved my life a couple of times.

For all the parameters see [robocopy docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Comment: thank you for the edit ! It is my first try to answer a question - I will improve my style :)

Comment: when it comes to `Start robocopy -args "$source $destination $fileList $robocopyOptions"` a cmd shows for like a milisecond and exits again and nothing happened. Maybe this is also a usefull info, i'm using it in a powershell script.

Comment: you can use `-NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait` for the window as recommended in the quoted link. But I prefer using logs with a timestamp in the name for each run.

Comment: I think i know the problem now. It works only with files not folders

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out you can do `Copy-Item -Path $path"\Desktop" -Destination $newdir -Recurse` and it will copy the Desktop folder with its content.